# Array and result table

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a two dimensional array that holds the choices from two users.  Now depending on the two choices there needs to be a random choosing of six different outcomes. These outcomes(integers) will be pulled, randomly, from a table.  For example:

Player A chooses option 3 and player B chooses option 1.  Now the intersection of 3 and 1 in the array will be a list of 6 outcomes -- maybe something like 2, 4, -1, 0, -11, -7, and the result will be one of those randomly chosen integers.

I have down how to enter the two choices into the index for the array but I am stumped on the next step.  How to use that index -- `playerChoice[3,1]` for example -- to access and return a random number from a list of 6 specific numbers.

Comment: Tips : show some code

Comment: Yes, you are strongly recommended to read through [this guide about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've removed tag from title and thank you notes from the post as not related to your question. Please provide information on what you tried and where exactly you are stuck (detailed error messages, input/expected output,...). Otherwise it will be possibly closed as "too broad" as teaching language basics is outside of scope of SO.

Comment: Store 6-arrays of "outcomes" at each position in your 2D array. Now it's simply a question of accessing `var outcome = arr[playerChoiceA][playerChoiceB][randomIntBetween0And5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I whipped up in sublime. I doubt it will compile but it should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

```
using Random;

numP1Choices = -1 //dummy value, I don't know how many options player 1 has to choose from
numP2Choices = -1 //same as above but for player 2

int [,,] outcome = new int[numP1Choices,numP2Choices,6] //

// build the array
for(int i = 0; i < numP1Choices; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numP2Choices; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            outcome[i,j,k] = SOME_OUTCOME;
        }
    }
}

// a random outcome
int p1Choice = 3
int p2Choice = 1

Random r = new Random();
int random = r.Next(6);
randomOutcome = outcome[p1Choice, p2Choice, random];
```

Hope that helps. However, in the future please provide some code and listen to the comments on your post.